# how to use apply functions with multiple parameters？

Tags: python, apply, python-polars

Now I have a dataframe:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[2,3,4,5,6],"c":[3,4,5,6,7]})`

the fuction:

```
def fun(a,b,shift_len): 
     return a+b*shift_len,b-shift_len
```

I can get the result by:

```
df[["d","e"]] = df.apply(lambda row:fun(row["a"],row["b"],3),axis=1,result_type="expand")
```

I want to know how can i use polars to get the same result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Note that this is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related problems. Thus, please [edit] your question to include the [tag:python] tag, so that Python users can find your question more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments with args

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[2,3,4,5,6],"c":[3,4,5,6,7]})


def t(df, row1, row2, shift_len):
    return df[row1] + df[row2] * shift_len, df[row2] - shift_len


df1[["d", "e"]] = df1.apply(t, args=("a", "b", 3), axis=1, result_type="expand")
print(df1)

OUTPUT:

   a  b  c   d  e
0  1  2  3   7 -1
1  2  3  4  11  0
2  3  4  5  15  1
3  4  5  6  19  2
4  5  6  7  23  3
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends on whether you can rewrite your function using Polars expressions.

### Using Polars Expressions

To obtain the best performance with Polars, try to code your calculations using [Expressions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/intro.html).  Expressions yield the most performant, embarrassingly parallel solutions.

For example, your function could be expressed as:

```py
shift_len = 3
df.with_columns(
    [
        (pl.col("a") + (pl.col("b") * shift_len)).alias("d"),
        (pl.col("b") - shift_len).alias("e"),
    ]
)
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ -1  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 11  ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 15  ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 19  ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Polars will run both expressions in parallel, yielding very fast results.

### Using `apply`

Let's assume that you cannot code your function as Polars Expressions (e.g., you need to use an external library).  Since your function takes multiple parameters and returns multiple values, we'll take this in steps.

##### Passing multiple values

We can pass multiple values to the the `fun` function in the `apply` by "stamp-coupling" multiple columns into a single series using [`polars.struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.struct.html).  In the lambda function, the values are passed as a Python `dict`, with the names of the columns as the keys.  So, for example, we access the value in column `a` in the lambda below as `cols["a"]`.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.struct(["a", "b"])
    .apply(lambda cols: fun(cols["a"], cols["b"], 3))
    .alias("result")
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ result  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ object  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ (7, -1) │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ (11, 0) │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ (15, 1) │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ (19, 2) │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   ┆ (23, 3) │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

The `result` column contains the tuples returned by the `fun` function.  However, note the type of the `result` column: `object`.  Columns of type `object` are not very useful in Polars, and have limited functionality.

##### Handling multiple return values

Next we'll convert the tuple returned by the `fun` function to something more useful: a dictionary of key-value pairs, where the keys are the desired column names (`d` and `e` in your example).

We'll accomplish this by using Python's `zip` function and a tuple with the desired names.

When we run this code, we will get a column of type `struct`.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.struct(["a", "b"])
    .apply(lambda cols: dict(zip(("d", "e"), fun(cols["a"], cols["b"], 3))))
    .alias("result")
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ result    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ struct[2] │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ {7,-1}    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ {11,0}    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ {15,1}    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ {19,2}    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   ┆ {23,3}    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

The names `d` and `e` do not appear in the output of the `result` column, but they are there.

##### Using `unnest`

In the last step, we'll use the [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) function to break the struct into two new columns.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.struct(["a", "b"])
    .apply(lambda cols: dict(zip(("d", "e"), fun(cols["a"], cols["b"], 3))))
    .alias("result")
).unnest("result")
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ -1  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 11  ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 15  ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 19  ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   ┆ 23  ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

**One caution**: using `apply` with external libraries and/or custom Python bytecode subjects your code to the Python GIL.  The result is very slow, single-threaded performance - **no matter how it is coded**.  As such, I strongly suggest avoiding the use of `apply` and custom Python functions, and instead trying to code your algorithms using only Polars Expressions, if you can.